# How to attach ID to imported and numpy array converted images?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing

I am importing images into Python and converting them to numpy arrays to do similarity analysis. Each file has a name of the type "32451.png". What I would like to do is to somehow attach the file name, in this example "32451" to each element in the array. I need to do this because I have a list of train/test elements based on that file number so I need to be able to divide them up. The code I'm currently using below brings in the images and converts them to a numpy array, but as far as I can tell does not save an identifier off anywhere that I could use to relate back to the image file name.

```
imgs=[]
path="Documents/data/img"
os.listdir(path)
valid_images =[".png"]

for f in os.listdir(path):
    ext= os.path.splitext(f)[1]
    if ext.lower() not in valid_images:
        continue
    imgs.append(np.asarray(Image.open(os.path.join(path,f))))
```

Comment: You could put the data into a dictionary with the ID as the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion, here is the code I was able to come up with.

```
imgs_dict={}
path="Documents/data/img"
os.listdir(path)
valid_images =[".png"]

for f in os.listdir(path):
    ext= os.path.splitext(f)[1]
    if ext.lower() not in valid_images:
        continue
    img_name=os.path.basename(f)
    img_name=os.path.splitext(img_name)[0]
    img=np.asarray(Image.open(os.path.join(path,f)))
    imgs_dict.update([(img_name,img)])
```